# Uneven sequence where highest number changes

Tags: r, sequence

I'm generating a lot of maps, where the breaks changes. I want the same intervals, but the highest number changes from map to map. I could go with multiple `if`'s, but there must be a better way?

```
maxvalues <- c(453, 25)
breaks <- c(0,1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200)
```

From this I would like to get

```
0,1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200, 453
0,1,2,5,10,25
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the 'maxvalues', get the elements in 'breaks' that are less than it, concatenate with the the 'x', and `unlist`

```
unlist(lapply(maxvalues,function(x) c(breaks[breaks< x], x)))
#[1]   0   1   2   5  10  20  50 100 200 453   0   1   2   5  10  20  25
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like charm. Still trying to get my head around all the apply's.

Comment: @JeppeOlsen  As `maxvalues` is a vector.  By using `lapply`, it loop through each of the elements in that vector in a `list`, create the boolean expression (`breaks < x`), subset the `breaks` (`breaks[breaks < x]`), concatenate with the element (`c(breaks[...., x)`) and `unlist` to a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `breaks` is sorted, I think `findInterval` is well suited for your problem since with which you can find the largest number smaller than your defined max value. Here is how to go:

```
sapply(maxvalues, function(x) c(breaks[1:findInterval(x, breaks)], x))

#[[1]]
# [1]   0   1   2   5  10  20  50 100 200 453

#[[2]]
#[1]  0  1  2  5 10 20 25
```